# A code snippet of netty examples from netty.io seems have bugs

Tags: netty, rx-netty

The code snippet is：

```
        final ChannelFuture f = ctx.writeAndFlush(time); 
        f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {

            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                assert f == future;
                ctx.close();
            }
        });
```

What happens if ' final ChannelFuture f = ctx.writeAndFlush(time); ' executes very fast so that the next `addListener` code does not start yet. 
When the first line of code completes, the thread notifies all listeners that the operation is done, but at that time, there is no listener at all! 
After that, a new listener is added but no more notifications will be received!

Code source: http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-5.x.html

Answer (score 2):

The ChannelFuture retains its completion state so if a listener is added after completion, the "late" added listener is called back immediately on addition.

See the javadoc for [ChannelFuture.addListener(GenericFutureListener)](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelFuture.html#addListener(io.netty.util.concurrent.GenericFutureListener)), specifically the comment:

> If this future is already completed, the specified listener is
>   notified immediately.

See the impl for [DefaultPromise](http://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultPromise.html). Late listeners (i.e. listeners added once the future is complete) have their own handler (notifyLateListener).

Comment: Does this cause OutOfMemoryError if user forgot to add at least one listener?

Comment: The future is garbage collected once it is unreachable, and the state is fairly small, so I would say an OOM is unlikely unless you go out of your way to stash futures in a collection or the like.

Comment: However, this explanation still somehow could not convince me. Did you consult the source codes? ChannelFuture does not know when a listener would be added, and it also does not know when it should release the future result for gc purpose because it would be waiting for listener(s) according to your explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Well, updated answer seems to be better. According to your answer, the ChannelFuture retains its "completion state", but how long will it persist?

Comment: It won't be as persistent as you are ;) It will last as long as the object is reachable.